# jQuery HTML Replace Dynamically Loaded Ajax Content After Second Load

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

After about 20 hours of compulsive searching I have managed to get text replace to start working after dynamic content is executed to apply on the dynamic content.

```
$("body").one("mouseover", "span.help-more", function(index) {
    $('li#li').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var t = $this.text();
        $this.html(t.replace("&lt", "<").replace("&gt", ">"));
    });
});
```

However, once dynamic content is once again retrieved the second time or any time after that, the text is no longer replaced.

I tried to get around this (see example below) by removing "one" and changing it with "on", then copying the code to undo the events (reversing the t.replace) but that didn't work.

```
$("body").on("mouseover", "span.help-more", function(index) {
    $('li#li').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var t = $this.text();
        $this.html(t.replace("&lt", "<").replace("&gt", ">"));
    });
});

$("body").on("mouseout", "span.help-more", function(index) {
    $('li#li').each(function(index) {
        var $this = $(this);
        var t = $this.text();
        $this.html(t.replace("<", "&lt").replace(">", "&gt"));
    });
});
```

Can someone please help me? I've given this about 20 hours so far. I would be happy with any solutions.

**I should mention**: I would just run it "on", but then somehow the HTML tags get stripped away upon second execution, that's why I tried to execute, undo.

I would be happy if either:
-(1) "one" is refired after every click
-(2) "on" if i can undo changes onmouseout
-(3) "on" and it stops stripping away tags on second run
..or any option you may suggest that is effective..

Your help would be immensely appreciated!

edit:in case this helps **The Relevant HTML:**

```
    <ul>
    <li class="stone-list ng-scope" id="stone_913"><span class="check-span"><span class="check-span-botton"></span></span> <span class="shape-span ng-binding">pear</span> <span class="carat-span ng-binding">0.5</span> <span class="cut-span ng-binding">excellent</span> <span class="colour-span ng-binding">G</span> <span class="clarity-span ng-binding">VS2</span> <span class="price-span" content="stone.price" dir=""><span class="ng-scope">$ 1412</span></span> <span class="help-span"><span class="help-more"><span class="information-help-more"><span class="top-help-more"></span> <span class="center-help-more"></span></span></span></span></li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <!-- ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Shape pear</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Carat Weight 0.5</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Clarity VS2</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Color G</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Color Shade WH</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Cut excellent</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Polish VG</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Symmetry VG</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Fluoresence N</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Depth (%) 62.5</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Table (%) 61</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Certificate Type</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Number 6255152356</span></li><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
    <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more"><a href="[link]" style="color:yellow">Video Link</a></span></li>
    <li style="list-style: none"><span class="center-help-more"><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip --></span></li>
</ul><span class="bottom-help-more"></span> <span class="change-span"><span class="change-span-botton">Choose</span></span>
<ul></ul>
```

It's some crappy html tag replace by WordPress that's causing me to find a workaround.

Comment: Add the relevant HTML please.

Comment: You could store the original data in a variable before modifying it the first time. Then you could simply retrieve the data from your variable onmouseout.

Comment: I would like to help you! but don't quite understand what's you're trying to accomplish

Comment: Zakaria - I added it.
Siphalor - I don't understand. Can you please give a little more info?
jmmonetro - the script executes on every li item that's loaded, but when another list is loaded afterwards it no longer works.

Comment: Thanks @ZakariaAcharki! Can you show how the other script is loaded!

Comment: jimmontero - It's a huge script, I'm not sure exactly where it's called. Could this be it? It's all just a list of rows like this.

function render_tooltrip2($row) {

    $result = array();

    $result[] = array('name' => (' '), 'value' => '<a style="color:yellow"href="'.$row - > vidya_link.
        '">Video Link </a> ');

    return $result;

}

There's also this: 
    foreach($res as &$element){
      $element->tooltrip = $this->render_tooltrip2($element);
    }

I will also look into the javascript for how it's loaded, but its 1000 lines long and might take some time

Comment: There is nothing to hover on the selector! If you add some text, then the script works!

Comment: jmmontero I'll try what you said. So sorry for misspelling your name before!

Comment: Some quick issues I noticed: You are trying to mouseover a class that doesn't exist in the html. You use an id multiple times in the html (you cannot use an id more than once). You use .each() on an id selected by jquery. This will by definition never run more than once, since there can only be one id.

Comment: Ok, I tried it. Did not work. The selector does have an image to hover on. I don't think this is the problem.

Comment: Rmo - Thanks, I'll try what you said.

Comment: RMo - I checked. The span does exist. Just not in the code given. It's a parent. As for the IDs, they seem to respond fine to other queries, why not this one?

Comment: RMo - wait, are you talking about the javascript ID's? I'm looking over the responses and I think you might refer to my "copy paste edit" second code modification of the fhirst? will do some experimentation

Comment: You're rigth, the class actually existed (I missed it). You have an #li id for each li-item. You are only allowed one of each id in your html. I don't know if it is causing the problems you are having, but it is invalid html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of fixes to make. Here is a Working Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3cp2kddm/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li class="stone-list ng-scope" id="stone_913">
    <span class="check-span">
    <span class="check-span-botton"></span>
    </span>
    <span class="shape-span ng-binding">pear</span>
    <span class="carat-span ng-binding">0.5</span>
    <span class="cut-span ng-binding">excellent</span>
    <span class="colour-span ng-binding">G</span>
    <span class="clarity-span ng-binding">VS2</span>
    <span class="price-span" content="stone.price" dir="">
    <span class="ng-scope">$ 1412</span>
    </span>
    <span class="help-span">
    <span class="help-more">
      <span class="information-help-more ui-icon ui-icon-info">
        <span class="top-help-more"></span>
    <span class="center-help-more"></span>
    </span>
    </span>
    </span>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <!-- ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Shape pear</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Carat Weight 0.5</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Clarity VS2</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Color G</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Color Shade WH</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Cut excellent</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Polish VG</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Symmetry VG</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Fluoresence N</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Depth (%) 62.5</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Table (%) 61</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Certificate Type</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more">Number 6255152356</span></li>
  <!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip -->
  <li class="ng-binding ng-scope" id="li"><span class="center-help-more"><a href="[link]" style="color:yellow">Video Link</a></span></li>
  <li style="list-style: none"><span class="center-help-more"><!-- end ngRepeat: row in stone.tooltrip --></span></li>
</ul><span class="bottom-help-more"></span> <span class="change-span"><span class="change-span-botton">Choose</span></span>
<ul></ul>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  $(".stone-list").on("mousein mouseenter mouseleave mouseout", ".help-more", function(e) {
    $('.ng-binding').each(function(ind, el) {
      var $this = $(el);
      var t = $this.prop("innerHTML");
      console.log("HTML Content: ", t);
      if (e.type == "mouseleave") {
        t = t.replace(/&lt;/g, "<");
        t = t.replace(/&gt;/g, ">");
      } else {
        t = t.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
        t = t.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
      }
      console.log("HTML Converted: ", t.toString());
      $this.html(t);
    });
  });
});
```

First, you have non-unique `id` attribute `#li` on almost all of your `li` elements. This defeats your `.each()` function. The `id` attribute should be unique. I would suggest `<li id="li-1"></li>` where each id has a unique number.

Second, I assume your script has some object or image inside of `<span class="help-more"></span>` such that the user can mouse over it. I made use of jQuery UI to do this in my example. Since the event could be worded differently in different browsers, I suggest binding to a number of them. Then performing an action conditionally based on the event you are looking for. This can be done with:

```
$( selector ).on( "mouseenter mouseleave", handlerInOut );
```

As you want to replace `<` or `>` with their HTML Entities, those being `&lt;` and `&gt;`, make sure you're using the right entities. Your replacement function did not work globally; hence, it only replaced the first occurrence. Switching to a regular expression with the global flag addresses this.

```
t = t.replace(/</g, "&lt;");
t = t.replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Calling `.text()` will only get you the actual text value and not the HTML value. Advise using `.html()` or `.prop("innerHTML")`. Both supply the same results.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Or this: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/3cp2kddm/3/ bit shorter amount of code

Comment: Twisty godspeed, you are awesome. Right now I love you almost as much as my own mother. It works perfectly! I promise to one day once I get better at the languages I'm learning now to spread on the help I have received! I truly appreciate this a lot. I greatly appreciate the explanation you have given me as well! Will remember to upvote once I have enough reputation points! Much gratitude!